# Getting first commit message of branch

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I'm trying to extract the first commit message of a branch. I have made use of the [by range feature of git log](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-log) to filter out commits before I created the feature branch ("myfeaturebranch"), using the command:

```bash
git log main..myfeaturebranch --reverse --pretty=%s
```

This works locally on my laptop, returning a list of commits, for example:

```bash
commit message 1
commit message 2
commit message 3
commit message 4
```

However, when I run this inside a GitHub action, (ubuntu-latest, with a run script), it fails:

```bash
Run git log main..myfeaturebranch --reverse --pretty=%s
fatal: ambiguous argument 'main..myfeaturebranch': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

What am I missing? The myfeaturebranch branch has been pushed to remote, and I can see all of the commits in GitHub, I just can't successfully run this command.

Comment: Shallow clone perhaps? Maybe not all branches fetched? Maybe not even any branch checked out (headless)? Try to run `git branch` to get an idea of the state of the repo.

Comment: Oh that is interesting. git branch locally shows the feature branch and main, but git branch in GitHub, only shows the feature branch.

Comment: but then - even after doing a checkout with fetch-depth: 0, it doesn't show the main branch. I wonder why?

Comment: I did a git branch --all, and noticed that main is labeled as "remotes/origin/main", so when I changed the above code to Run git log remotes/origin/main..myfeaturebranch --reverse --pretty=%s, it worked! Thanks for the help @UlrichEckhardt!